# Microsoft XP on HP computer

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Had to do a system restore on my HP Pavillion 533W with OS - XP. Computer reverted back to initial install.  Now am unable to load IE 8 or SP2 or SP3. When attempting to load newer IE 8, I get this error message "Procedure Entry Point could not be located.  Dynamic link Library Kernel 32. DLL".  How do I restore my registry files?

Comment: You can't.  Your registry was wiped when you reinstalled the operating system.

Comment: FYI, a 'system restore' is different to 'restoring an image'. If you had made an image you could restore it but you probably haven't. Install Chrome, forget IE(at least for now). I haven't tested the latest Opera, but Opera 10.5 runs well on XP. Chrome perhaps less so. Chrome on sp2 is giving an error on https sites.  Can't comment on Chrome on XP sp3. Anyhow, try other browsers to IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another computer that has access to the internet, and is working normally, grab a thumb drive (USB flash drive) go to http://download.windows.com and manually download the offline (standalone) installers for SP1 (if it's not already there), SP2, SP3, and IE8 for windows XP. save them to the thumb drive, then install them on the XP computer in the following order:

SP1
SP2
SP3
IE8

I've had this problem multiple times, and this is the only way that I've found to resolve the issue, because XP without SP2 (and sometimes even without SP3) will not work correctly with windows updates, no matter how hard you try.